# ¿Por que un form con script si funciona en html pero en react no?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, reactjs, script

Estoy tratando de agregar un botón de epay a mi proyecto en react, pero el código del botón no funciona en react sin embargo en html si.

Este es el codigo en react:

```
import React, {useEffect, useState,useContext} from 'react'
import '../Styles/Producto.css'

const Producto = () => {

  return (
    <div>
      <header>

      </header>
      <main>
      
        <section className='info'>
          <h2>Producto muy bueno</h2>

          <h3>Este es un excelente producto</h3>
          <form>
            <script src='https://checkout.epayco.co/checkout.js'
                data-epayco-key='aqui tengo la llave' 
                class='epayco-button' 
                data-epayco-amount='11900' 
                data-epayco-tax='1900.00'  
                data-epayco-tax-ico='0.00'               
                data-epayco-tax-base='10000'
                data-epayco-name='Productos de drogueria' 
                data-epayco-description='Productos de drogueria' 
                data-epayco-currency='cop'    
                data-epayco-country='CO' 
                data-epayco-test='true' 
                data-epayco-external='false' 
                data-epayco-response=''  
                data-epayco-confirmation='' 
                data-epayco-button='https://multimedia.epayco.co/dashboard/btns/btn5.png'> 
            </script>
        </form>
          <h3>Precio: $180.000
        </h3>
        </section>
    </main>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Producto
```

El código del botón es la etiqueta form que contiene el script sin embargo no funciona, ni si quiera se muestra.

Comment: Desconozco reactjs, pero supongo que el navegador no va a interpretar y cargar la etiqueta `<script>` cuando proviene de un contenido dinámico. Revisa [este artículo](https://betterprogramming.pub/4-ways-of-adding-external-js-files-in-reactjs-823f85de3668) (en inglés) para ver algunas opciones disponibles.

Answer (score 0):

JSX no interpreta la etiqueta  por eso al integrar alguna librería externa es necesario hacer una investigación para integrarla con JSX (React) en este caso te dejo un ejemplo de la manera correcta de agregarlo en React:

Link: https://github.com/Chargily/chargily-epay-react-js

Espero te haya servido amigo, saludos